# Can't bind a connected socket

Tags: c#, sockets, bind

So I'm all new to this 'Socket' programming and there seems to be something I have fundamentally misunderstood ...

The documentation for the server I use is very poorly written, but says it uses a "streaming socket connection" that is "event based" ... the server is on the local network.

here is my first naive program flow (no async or anything!):

.........

1) First I need a Socket ... no problem ... I get that :)

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

2) Then I connect with it ... also no problem :)

```
s.Connect("10.10.10.36", 6009);
```

3) Now that I have my connection and I have the new local EP given by the server ... something like "10.10.10.59:56231" ... so I try to Bind to that EP :

```
s.Bind (s.LocalEndPoint);
```

After that I need to listen and begin accepting connections :

```
s.Listen (10);
s.Accept ();
```

.........

the "s.Bind (s.LocalEndPoint);" fails (I ran it without the debugger) with this :

.........

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Invalid arguments
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) [0x00065] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1115 
  at RFID.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002b] in /Users/jab/Projects/RFID/RFID/Program.cs:17 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Invalid arguments
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) [0x00065] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1115 
  at RFID.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002b] in /Users/jab/Projects/RFID/RFID/Program.cs:17
```

.........

Now I know this is very primitive question but I need to be pointed in the right direction :)

TIA.

Comment: You're mixing up both client and server. Bind is used server side and Connect is used in client side

Comment: I'll suggest you to make use of msdn [Socket Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx). First learn synchronous then jump to asynchronous.

Comment: To expand on what @SriramSakthivel said, servers bind and listen, and clients usually just connect. It is also possible to bind before connecting: In active-mode FTP, as the server (which listens on port #21) connects back to the client to transfer data, it's supposed to bind to port #20 first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you `connect`the socket. But you would only connect the client (not the server). To get a local endpoint to listen on, just create one yourself :

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 6009);
s.Bind (localEndPoint);
```

After this it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why bind() would not work for a client is because the connect() implicitly binds the client socket to a temporary port number. But, if you try to bind() before connect(), then it would succeed. So, for client side, all you need to do is open a socket and connect. For the server side, you would need to open a socket, bind it to a port, start listening, and then get pending connections using accept().